# Underscores below "pin code" layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement this type of layout without using a library:

[image]

I want to use one `EditText` field but my problem is to implement the underscores below the `EditText` fields under the current number and make it dynamic. Any tips of how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this use `horizontal LinearLayout`

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDigit1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDigit2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="2"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDigit3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="3"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDigit4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="4"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any possible way to make it in one single EditText and add dynamic underscores (eg. change its color and thickness after successful input) below each number-input?

Comment: You can't do it with one edittext, but you can make the code quite simple and modular, use this tutorial I wrote: https://medium.com/@Lev_Sharone/create-your-own-customized-pin-code-layout-in-3-simple-steps-e36d560689f8